# Unable to save control properties in Form/LayoutView in MS Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I have a strange problem with my form.

A week or so back, I was able to change the Tab Control's Page property .Visible to True/False with a few macros. I did through a button in FormView. I could change most properties from Form/LayoutView with macros.

Currently I cannot for some reason. I can change the page's .Visible property to True or False from FormView and LayoutView, but it won't save when the form opens up again. In order for it to save, I need to go into DesignView manually and set it (which doesn't work for my purposes).

The macro also changes each control's Tag to "1" as well, that does not work in FormView or LayoutView anymore either. I also tried renaming some labels through LayoutView, but they won't save either.

I have the below code to un-hide all pages

```
Dim ctrl As Control
Dim tabCtl As TabControl
Dim pgctrl As Page

'Define how to handle errors
On Error GoTo HandleCall

For Each pgctrl In Me.TabCtl46.Pages
    'Set Pages as visible
     pgctrl.Visible = True
Next pgctrl

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
'Remove insibility tag-property from controls
ctrl.Tag = ""
Next ctrl

'Call Error Handler if error is not harmless
HandleCall:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Call ErrorHandle(Err.Number, Err.Description, Err.Source)
Else
End If
```

And I have this code for setting a page to invisible. The TextBox is the on the first page. I have 10 pages total and 1 tab control.

```
Dim ctrl As Control

'Define how to handle errors
On Error GoTo HandleCall

'Move focus to prevent errors
Me.Text684.SetFocus
'Hide Page
Me.RenameMe2.Visible = False

'And put the tag-property for invisibility on all controls
For Each ctrl In Me.RenameMe.Controls
    ctrl.Tag = "1"
Next ctrl

'Call Error Handler if error is not harmless
HandleCall:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Call ErrorHandle(Err.Number, Err.Description, Err.Source)
Else
End If
```

Any insight is deeply appreciated. I've been troubleshooting the code, running back and forth...and it kind of seems like Form/LayoutView and DesignView are disconnected from each other to me.

Comment: Changes like these, when done in Form view, *never* persist after closing the form. I'm not sure about Layout view, I never use it. To make these changes permanent, you have to go to Design view. Or make them at runtime, e.g. in Form_Open().

Comment: Weird...I'm 100% certain that they saved a week or two back. Is there a way to save these changes on Form_Unload()? Executing them at Runtime can't work since such changes are made during the operation of the form.

Comment: Thanks for the response Andre. I ended up putting more code at Runtime which takes into account what is written in a back-end table and adjusts the Pages' .Visible property and the Controls' .Tag property accordingly. Works well now!